# Codeigniter route and function confusion

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

Below I have a function that gives me a url for every listingId that is found.

Is it possible to do this via a route?

At this stage I want to load a view for each `$subCat`but use the `$mainCat`as a main navigational item with the `$subCat` as a sub dropdown option that loads the specific view.

```
  $detailsFunction = $this->createCategoryDetails();

  $ld = array();
  $url = array();

  foreach ($detailsFunction as $main) 
  {
   $ld = array('listingId' => $main['listingId']);

   foreach($ld as $id)
   {
    $mainlisting = $main['listingId'];
    $mainCat     = strtolower($main['mainCat']);
    $subCatO     = strtolower($main['subCat']);
    $subCat      = str_replace(" ", "-", $subCatO);

    $structure = base_url().'listings/'.$mainCat.'/'.$subCat;

    var_dump($structure);

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's what routing is for.

You can do something like this (not sure about the syntax, play around with it):

```
$routes['listings/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'listings/$1/$2';
```

and your listings should be :

```
function listings($mainCat,$subCat)
```

**EDIT:**
Not sure about your question now that i read it again, u might be needing is (in case theres a difference between mainCat and subCat to just pass 1 segment to listings and just act accordingly

Comment: Thanks,  I am glad to know that I was thinking on the same path